# Debugging server script like python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, networking, network-programming

I'm new to 'network' programming. I've done throughout the Google app engine tutorial and I'm trying to make my own application which is guestbook. It has a server script on Google app engine and client app is running on iPhone.

But how do I check if the server is received my message from iPhone? 
or How do I debug the script I wrote on server side? (it's an python script)

I want to make sure the data is in right format and other stuff.

Please somebody give me a link if there's good tutorial or good place to start. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you should be using tons of [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) calls. In the app engine dashboard for your app there is an option to view logs, and all of your logging calls will show up in there (and can be filtered in various ways).

There are also ways to run `dev_appserver.py` and debug locally using software like PyDev, but you'd have to make your iPhone app send its messages to the address of your local server.

Comment: WOw, this is a good tip! I'm going to try it right now. thanks ;)